# Existe algo como fluent nhibernate para hibernate do java?

Tags: java, hibernate

Sei que `fluent nhibernate`(hibernate versão para .net) usa `lambdas` e que `java` só implementou agora na versão 8.

Mas existe alguma forma de configuração do `hibernate` do `java` através de código? e não através de `xml`'s?

Comment: Desculpe, entendi o inverso...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `hibernate` os mapeametos já podem ser feitos utilizando anotações.

Como no exemplo:

```
package model;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="PESSOA")
public class Pessoa {
    private int id;
    private String rg;
    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private String estado;
    private String cidade;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="PESSOA_ID")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="PESSOA_RG", nullable=false)
    public String getRg() {
        return rg;
    }
    public void setRg(String rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }

    @Column(name="PESSOA_NOME", nullable=false)
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Column(name="PESSOA_IDADE")
    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }
    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    @Column(name="PESSOA_ESTADO")
    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }
    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    @Column(name="PESSOA_CIDADE")
    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }
    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }
}
```

[Ref 1](http://javafree.uol.com.br/artigo/874971/Acessando-Dados-com-Java-Parte-3-Hibernate-Annotations.html#ixzz2xf4iYKp4)

[Documentação](http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/) do hibernate.

Comment: Bom isso já me ajuda também, similar ao entity framework(via annotations) obrigado!

Comment: O que eu não gosto muito dessa ideia, é associar o mapeamento ao layer de negócio

Comment: A associação existe, mas ela é fraca. Se existe algum impedimento você pode utilizar o mapeamento em XML como opção.